# Embedding arrays in structs

Tags: c, struct

Consider two ways of defining a struct

```
typedef struct foo1 {
    int type;
    unsigned char* data;
}

...

struct *foo1 bla = malloc(sizeof(struct foo1));
bla->data = malloc(100);
```

and

```
typedef struct foo2 {
    int type;
    unsigned char data[]; //note: last element, so we can malloc dynamically
}

...

struct *foo2 bla = malloc(sizeof(struct foo2) + 100);
```

I guess the advantages of the foo2 method is

- we save `sizeof(void*)` bytes of memory and
- we save a memory lookup when accessing `bla->data`.

The advantages of foo1 is

- We can have any amount of dynamically allocated pointers in our struct, while with foo2 we are limited to one (since it has to be the last element)
- Overwriting `bla->data` with another pointer is easier/faster

My understanding, that I would like sanity checked, is that if you plan to construct thousands of `fooN`s and you're sure you only need one dynamically allocated element, then you should go for the foo2 method, otherwise the loss in readability and extensibility does not seem worth it. Is this basically correct?

EDIT: I thought the C++ sidenote in the comments was very interesting and would not mind elaboration on this point - if using `foo2` means that there will exist C++ compilers that will not accept your code, then that is certainly something to take into account when making your decision, right?

Comment: Personally C but I'd be very interested in knowing if the answer differs in C++

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist latter is ill-formed in C++. Former is typically implemented using `std::vector`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist yes. That is what ill-formed means.

Comment: So hypothetically if I were to implement some data structure in C that used foo2, a C++ compiler would not allow me to import it?

Comment: Way #1 may require padding between `type` and `data`.  Way #2 does not with `unsigned char data[]`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist no that's not the case.  They are talking about proper form and safety.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist A C++ compiler would not be required by the standard to succesfully compile a program if it included a header which defined the structure. Declaring the member `unsigned char data[1];` would be well-formed alternative.

Comment: Recommend to drop one of the language tags.  Since C++ interest is ancillary, suggest dropping that.

Comment: "you plan to construct thousands of fooNs"... and "loss in readability and extensibility" is the crux of this question.  Which is more important? Space/performance or maintainability. You Can't Have Your Kate And Edith Too.

Comment: @ValentinRadu You don't really add anything with the second case, foo2 will take up 104 bytes and foo1 will take up 112 (if pointers are 8 bytes and ints are 4 of course, and discounting compiler padding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I guess the advantages of the foo2 method is
>
> - we save `sizeof(void*)` bytes of memory and
> - we save a memory lookup when accessing `bla->data`.

They're a few advantages, yes. You also have only *one* allocation, which is great because people tend to forget to free the *second* one. Not to mention, the overhead in storage, behind the scenes, for the second allocation is likely more than `sizeof (void *)` bytes.

> The advantages of foo1 is
>
> - We can have any amount of dynamically allocated pointers in our struct, while with foo2 we are limited to one (since it has to be the last element)
> - <strike>Overwriting `bla->data` with another pointer is easier/faster</strike>

Notice how I've crossed out the second point there? Think about it... The only reason you'd overwrite `bla->data` with another pointer is to resize it, in which case you've written something like `void *temp = realloc(bla->data, new_size);`.

What's the alternative in the foo2 case? `void *temp = realloc(bla, sizeof *bla + new_size);`, yes? That's a smaller memory footprint and a slightly simpler expression... I'd suggest this *might just be a little bit faster*, because it seems *more cache friendly* to me, but *only* if you're using *one* of these allocations.

That's a complication to this answer. If you *do* plan on allocating thousands of elements, you should consider the normalised form of your data structure (i.e. like you'd design a commercial database). When you need to resize a single `bla[n]->data`, that needs to be simple, yet when you need to resize the entire array of `bla`, that also needs to be a simple task. This means the `data` member should be a *separate allocation* to the `bla` allocation. Keep your allocations to a minimum; in that case you only need two of them, and just keep using `realloc` to resize them when necessary.

Most common home desktop/laptop computers nowadays should have virtually no problem dealing with thousands of such items, even up to several hundred KB in size each item.

Always remember, write your code for ease of maintenance. It's simple enough to fire up your profiler and work out where to optimise (and whether you optimised correctly) later on, and this way you'll pollute less code with unreadable crud and be much less likely to miss the target.

---

> EDIT: I thought the C++ sidenote in the comments was very interesting and would not mind elaboration on this point - if using foo2 means that there will exist C++ compilers that will not accept your code, then that is certainly something to take into account when making your decision, right?

Your code won't compile in C++, anyway, as C++ doesn't have implicit `void` pointer conversion required for your example use of `malloc`... and you *really* shouldn't write C-style C++. We've already explained to death as a community why not. I'll leave that information as an exercise for you to find by yourself.

P.S. Remember to `free` the second allocation ;)